# react-native-maps iOS build issues when using use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, cocoapods

Main errors: **`GMUHeatmapTileLayer.h not found`** and
**`GMUKMLParser.h` not found.**

This is how my Podfile looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
    
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
    
platform :ios, '10.0'
    
 
target 'myProject' do
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps';
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils',


  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
  :path => config[:reactNativePath],
  # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
  :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'react-native-document-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-document-picker'

  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK',  '~> 7.69.0'

  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0.0'

  pod 'RNPhotoEditor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-photo-editor/ios'

  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  pod 'iOSPhotoEditor', :git => 'https://github.com/prscX/photo-editor', :branch => 'master'


  post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name.include?('iOSPhotoEditor')
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5'
        end
      end
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
      end

      if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
        end
      end

      if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # Follow [Flipper iOS Setup Guidelines][https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/ios-native/]
  # This is required because iOSPhotoEditor is implementated using Swift
  $static_framework = ['FlipperKit', 'Flipper', 'Flipper-Folly',
    'CocoaAsyncSocket', 'ComponentKit', 'Flipper-DoubleConversion',
    'Flipper-Glog', 'Flipper-PeerTalk', 'Flipper-RSocket', 'Yoga', 'YogaKit',
    'CocoaLibEvent', 'OpenSSL-Universal', 'boost-for-react-native']

  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
        if $static_framework.include?(pod.name)
          def pod.build_type;
            Pod::BuildType.static_library
          end
        end
      end
  end
end
```

After adding the code for `react-native-photo-editor` that requires `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

`react-native-maps` cannot find the `google-maps-ios-utils` files.

`GMUHeatmapTileLayer.h file not found`

I've tried manually adding `google-maps-ios-utils` as described here:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/b721e95a500d0c9a4fd93738e83fc86c2a57ac89/Swift.md

but still no way for those files to be accessed by `AirGoogleMaps` files:

[image]

Deps:

```
RN: 0.64.0
react-native-maps: 0.28
Google-Maps-iOS-Utils: 2.1.0
GoogleMaps: 3.5.0
```

Has anyone succeeded using the `react-native-maps` with google maps and `use_frameworks!`?

Is there something wrong with my pod file?

How can I make this `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils: 2.1.0` work?

Has anyone some steps to add this library manually and make it build with a bridging header in RN 0.64 with the use_frameworks as above?

I also tried all the steps from this answer but same error as in print screen image shows up.

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3536#issuecomment-683563649

More info about node_modules deps:

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.14.1",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "2.0.2",
"@react-native-community/google-signin": "5.0.0",
"@react-native-community/hooks": "2.6.0",
"@react-native-community/image-editor": "2.3.0",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.0",
"@sentry/browser": "6.2.3",
"@sentry/react-native": "2.4.0",
"@svgr/webpack": "4.2.0",
"@xobotyi/scrollbar-width": "1.9.5",
"abortcontroller-polyfill": "1.7.1",
"bfj": "6.1.1",
"case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
"color": "3.1.3",
"cross-fetch": "3.1.2",
"css-loader": "1.0.1",
"dotenv": "6.2.0",
"dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
"file-loader": "2.0.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.4",
"leaflet": "1.7.1",
"lokijs": "1.5.11",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.4",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
"pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.2.1",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
"postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
"postcss-preset-env": "6.5.0",
"postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
"query-string": "6.6.0",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dev-utils": "10.2.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-leaflet": "3.1.0",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"react-native-admob": "2.0.0-beta.6",
"react-native-device-info": "8.0.7",
"react-native-document-picker": "5.0.2",
"react-native-fs": "2.16.6",
"react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "2.2.0",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.36.0",
"react-native-image-size": "1.1.3",
"react-native-local-mongodb": "2.2.9",
"react-native-maps": "0.28.0",
"react-native-photo-editor": "^1.0.10",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
"react-native-sensitive-info": "5.5.8",
"react-native-splash-screen": "3.2.0",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "8.1.0",
"react-native-web": "0.15.0",
"react-router": "5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
"resolve": "1.10.0",
"rn-fetch-blob": "0.12.0",
"sass-loader": "7.1.0",
"style-loader": "0.23.1",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
"ts-events": "3.4.0",
"typescript": "4.0.5",
"url-loader": "1.1.2",
"uuid": "3.4.0",
"webpack": "4.41.6",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
},
"resolutions": {
  "typescript": "4.0.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.12.9",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.12.13",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.12.13",
"@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "7.12.13",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.12.15",
"@babel/polyfill": "7.12.1",
"@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
"@carimus/metro-symlinked-deps": "1.1.0",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.19.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.19.0",
"babel-jest": "26.6.3",
"babel-loader": "8.2.2",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "4.0.0",
"babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "0.2.3",
"babel-plugin-react-native-web": "0.15.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.9.4",
"babel-preset-react-app": "7.0.2",
"eslint": "7.19.0",
"jest": "26.6.3",
"jetifier": "^1.6.6",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
"mockdate": "2.0.5",
"moment-timezone": "0.5.33",
"path-exists": "4.0.0",
"react-error-overlay": "6.0.6",
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
"sftp-sync-deploy": "0.7.1",
"yarn-run-all": "3.1.1"
},
```

Additional notes:

The build process got broken (triggering a new crash relates to rn-maps) when I added
`https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor` (which requires `use_frameworks`).
If I remove this module and the extra settings associated with it from `Podfile` everything is ok.

Comment: can you please give a screenshot of your package.json file?

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN I edited the question and added full info about node_modules. My target is to have both react-native-maps (with google maps) and react-native-photo-editor in the same project.

Comment: Thanks, I am taking a look at those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to build the project with `react-native-maps` and `use_frameworks` as described in the question I had to fork the `react-native-maps` library and replace

`Google-Maps-iOS-Utils` with `Google_Maps_iOS_Utils` in header imports in

**`lib/ios/AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMap.m`:**

```
#import <Google_Maps_iOS_Utils/GMUKMLParser.h>
#import <Google_Maps_iOS_Utils/GMUPlacemark.h>
#import <Google_Maps_iOS_Utils/GMUPoint.h>
#import <Google_Maps_iOS_Utils/GMUGeometryRenderer.h>
```

and in **`lib/ios/AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMapHeatmap.h`:**

```
#import <Google_Maps_iOS_Utils/GMUHeatmapTileLayer.h>
```

If anybody knows a better solution than this, I will be happy to accept it and if the answer is added in next few days I will grant it the bounty attached to the question.

I will probably keep the fork until `react-native-maps` is updated to have a newer version of `google-maps-ios-utils`(in v3 i think the issue is fixed).

`"react-native-maps": "https://github.com/fdobre/react-native-maps#hot-fix-use-frameworks-ios",`

Comment: is it working? I've able to import GMUHeatmapTileLayer.h but that causes another problem ( unable to find "GMULatLng" in this scope). I will give it another day to solve it.

Comment: I'll post my findings tomorrow whether it's working or not.

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN please add an answer only if it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Here is working [project](https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/react-native-maps-with-use-famework) build with basic requirment (react-native-maps with user frameworks and react-native-photo-editor).

### Add AirMaps and AirGoogleMaps.

[source](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3536#issuecomment-683563649)

1. Right click on your project and click `Add files to <projecjName>`
   [image: right click on project and click "Add Files to "projectName"]
2. goto -> `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/`
3. Select both AirMaps and AirGoogleMaps
4. Make sure the option `create groups` and your target is selected.

[image: Add AirMaps and AirGoogleMaps]

### Add Airmaps folder to Library Search Path:

1. Goto target->build settings-> search for library search path and add the following line (with quotation) for both debug and release, `"$(PODS_ROOT)/../../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps"`

[image: add AirMaps folder to library search path for Debug]

[image: add AirMaps folder to library search path for Release]

### Add google-maps-ios-utils:

According to these official [instruction](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/b721e95a500d0c9a4fd93738e83fc86c2a57ac89/Swift.md#integrating-with-swift-projects-which-use-use_frameworks-in-the-podfile)

1. `git clone https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils` on ios folder with a different name. We need only the content of `src` folder.
2. On XCODE, Right click on a project and create a group named `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils`.[image: creating a new group Google-Maps-iOS-Utils]
3. Right click on that folder and click `Add files to ...`
4. Select all the folders of `src` directory of previously cloned directory of step(i).
5. Make sure the the options is selected "create groups" and target is selected as your app target.
   [image: add all the folder in src folder to google-maps-ios-utils group]
6. Delete the `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Heatmap/HeatMapInterpolationPoint.swift file` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3536#issuecomment-683563649). Select remove reference when deleting.
7. Goto project -> build settings -> search for `preprocessor macros` and add the following for both Debug and Release.

   `HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1`

   `HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS_UTILS=1`

[image: Adding HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1 and HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS_UTILS=1 to preprocessor macros in build settings]

### Duplicate Symbol Error

As we have manually added AirGoogleMaps, AirMaps, Google-Maps-iOS-Utils we may get error:

> Error: ld: 658 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

solution:

1. Delete `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils` from `Pods/Pods` pods section (select the option "Remove References"). Because we have manually added `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils` Manually.
   [image: Delete Google-Maps-iOS-Utils]

if we compile we'll get `ld: 470 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`.

1. Delete `react-native-maps` and `react-native-google-maps` from `Pods/Development Pods`
   [image: Delete react-native-maps and react-native-google-maps]

`(This is the repetitive task)` All 3 folders that are removed here, will regenerate everything `pod install` execute.

### Update 1:

Here is what my Pod file looks like:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'myAwesomeProject' do
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'myAwesomeProjectTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()
  pod 'RNPhotoEditor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-photo-editor/ios'
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
pod 'iOSPhotoEditor', :git => 'https://github.com/prscX/photo-editor', :branch => 'master'

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  flipper_post_install(installer) # as stated here https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native-ios/#react-native-063
  if target.name.include?('iOSPhotoEditor')
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5'
    end
  end
  if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No' # as mentioned here https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3597#issuecomment-745026120
    end
  end
  if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec')) #as mentioned here https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/842#issuecomment-812543933
    target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
      if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
        target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
      end
    end
  end
end
end 

$static_framework = ['FlipperKit', 'Flipper', 'Flipper-Folly',
'CocoaAsyncSocket', 'ComponentKit', 'Flipper-DoubleConversion',
'Flipper-Glog', 'Flipper-PeerTalk', 'Flipper-RSocket', 'Yoga', 'YogaKit',
'CocoaLibEvent', 'OpenSSL-Universal', 'boost-for-react-native']


pre_install do |installer|
Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if $static_framework.include?(pod.name)
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.static_library
      end
    end
  end
end



  # post_install do |installer|
  #   react_native_post_install(installer)
  # end
end
```

### Update 2:

If your problem is not solved by the above answer. Please follow the instructions on my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/react-native-maps-with-use-famework) step by step.

### Update 3:

Error: 'Google-Maps-iOs-Utils/GMUKMLParser.h' file not found

[image: problem with import statement]

Solution:

react-native-maps official guide [says](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#build-issues-with-google-maps-ios-utils-ios) to follow this instructions on [`google-maps-ios-utils/Swift.md`](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/b721e95a500d0c9a4fd93738e83fc86c2a57ac89/Swift.md). However these instructions are vague. [Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/86#issuecomment-310500599) is a more clear instructions set:

1. We already have cloned and added google-maps-ios-utils above .If you haven't, please follow these instructions avobe.
2. Create Swift Bridging Header

   1. File > New > File > Header File
   2. Usually the name would be [Project Name]-Bridging-Header.h but you name it whatever you want. I am naming it just `Header.h` in this project as it is really a simple project.[image: new file][image: select file type][image: select location for header file][image: final header file location]
   3. Goto target->Build Settings->search for `Swift Compiler - General`

      1. In `Objective-C Bridging Header` put `Header.h`.[image: linking the bridging header]
3. Put these following line on the header file:

   ```sh
   #import "GMUMarkerClustering.h"
   #import "GMUGeoJSONParser.h"
   #import "GMUKMLParser.h"
   #import "GMUGeometryRenderer.h"
   ```
4. Put these following line in `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Clustering/GMUMarkerClustering.h`

   ```sh
   #import "GMUCluster.h"
   #import "GMUClusterItem.h"
   #import "GMUClusterManager.h"
   #import "GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator.h"
   #import "GMUDefaultClusterRenderer.h"
   #import "GMUGridBasedClusterAlgorithm.h"
   #import "GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.h"
   #import "GMUStaticCluster.h"

   #import "GQTPointQuadTree.h"
   ```
5. `(This is a repetitive task. you need to do this step every time "yarn install" executes)`Change to import statement to `#import "GMUHeatmapTileLayer.h"` in `AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMapHeatmap.h` file. [image: changing the import statement in AIRGoogleMapHeatman.h]
6. `(This is a repetitive task. you need to do this step every time "yarn install" executes)` Put these following line in `AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMap.m`

   ```sh
   #import "GMUKMLParser.h"
   #import "GMUPlacemark.h"
   #import "GMUPoint.h"
   #import "GMUGeometryRenderer.h"
   ```

[image: changing the import statement in AirGoogleMap.m]

### Update 4:

In comment, @Florin mentioned of an error

> Build input files cannot be found: '/ios/master/src/GeometryUtils/Internal/CatesianPoint.swift'...'

which caused because I didn't know how to use submodules in git. So, when cloned google-maps-ios-utils, that repo doesn't get pushed to my GitHub repo(mentioned in the first line of this answer). That problem is fixed. I have just added the ```src`` folder content without cloning the whole repo in my repo and pushed the changes.

Comment: @Florin take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN! Please also add the content of your Podfile to your answer.

Comment: Added the pod file content. @FlorinDobre

Comment: I pulled the content of your repo, ran yarn, ran pod install, removed the 3 pods as you suggested and got error: Build input files cannot be found: '/ios/master/src/GeometryUtils/Internal/CatesianPoint.swift', '/ios/master/src/GeometryUtils/GMSPolyline+GeometryUtils.swift', '/ios/master/src/GeometryUtils/Math.swift', '/ios/master/src/GeometryUtils/Internal/LatLngRadians.swift', '/ios/master/src/GeometryUtils/CLLocationCoordinate2D+GeometryUtils.swift', ... '/ios/master/src/GeometryUtils/GMSPolygon+GeometryUtils.swift' (in target 'myAwesomeProject' from project 'myAwesomeProject')

Comment: What else needs to be done to make your repo build?

Comment: You need to import google-maps-ios-utils manually to work this out.

Comment: Follow the section of my answer "Add google-maps-ios-utils:"

Comment: Ignore the previous comment.If you want to solve this problem you need to follow the step 2 mentioned here in the project readme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231166/discussion-between-mrpmohiburrahman-and-florin-dobre).

Comment: Downside of this solution: many manual links and having to remove 3 pods manually after each pod install. I wasn't able to make the repo you provided build, perhaps you used a newer version of google-maps-ios-utils there. Thank you for you work. Since you are the only one that answered my question during the bounty period I will grant you the bounty.

Comment: Yes, A lot of repetitive tasks need to be done on every yarn install and pod install.
I wish I could make a script to automate this. Also, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add google maps and firebase both so needed to avoid use_framwork. This is what has worked from me after two days got wasted on it.

solution is to use firebase pods like this

```
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true  
  pod 'FirebaseStorageInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseMessagingInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
```

as explained on this link. give that person a thumbs up as well.

https://dev.to/matthewzruiz/firebase-the-following-swift-pods-cannot-yet-be-integrated-as-static-libraries-b59

my pod file:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'ReactNativeBoilerPlate' do

  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

  config = use_native_modules!
# React Native Maps dependencies
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  target 'ReactNativeBoilerPlateTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"
      end
    end
  end
 
end
```